# Integral transform in finite range

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, integral-transforms

Fourier transform is an integral transform in infinite range, it can be used for solving constant coefficient linear differential equations defined in $(-\infty,+\infty)$.

Laplace transform is an integral transform in semi-infinite range, it can be used for solving initial value problem (IVP) of constant coefficient linear differential equations defined in $[0,+\infty)$.

Then does there exist integral transform(s) in finite range so I can use it for solving boundary value problem (BVP) of constant coefficient linear differential equations defined in e.g. $[a,b]$?

To make the question more specific, can I solve the following BVP

$$\frac{\partial ^2u(x,y)}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial ^2u(x,y)}{\partial y^2}=1$$
$$u(0,y)=0,\ u(1,y)=0$$ $$u(x,0)=0,\ u(x,2)=0$$

in $[0,1]×[0,2]$ with some kind of integral transform? (Yeah I don't want to use separation of variable. )

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there exist such transforms, including but not limited to finite Fourier transforms and finite Hankel transforms. A detailed introduction can be found in Chapter 10 and Chapter 13 of [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1482223570), and an implementation of finite Fourier transform in *Mathematica* can be found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155817/1871).

In the rest part of the answer, I'll solve the specific example mentioned in the question with `finiteFourierSinTransform`. First, interpret the equation to *Mathematica* code:

```
With[{u = u[x, y]},
 eq = Laplacian[u, {x, y}] == 1;
 bc@x = u == 0 /. {{x -> 0}, {x -> 1}};
 bc@y = u == 0 /. {{y -> 0}, {y -> 2}};]
```

Then transform the equation with `finiteFourierSinTransform`:

```
(* Definition of finiteFourierSinTransform isn't included in this post,
   please find it in the link above. *)
{teq, tbc@y} = 
 finiteFourierSinTransform[{eq, bc@y}, {x, 0, 1}, n] /. Rule @@@ bc@x /. 
  HoldPattern@finiteFourierSinTransform[a_, __] :> a
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> **Remark**
>
> Notice I've stripped off `finiteFourierSinTransform`. Just remember
>   that `u[t, x]` actually denotes `finiteFourierSinTransform[u[t, x],
>   {x, 0, a}, n]` in `{teq, tbc@y}`.

Next step is to transform the equation again, this time with respect to `y`:

```
tteq = finiteFourierSinTransform[teq, {y, 0, 2}, m] /. Rule @@@ tbc@y /. 
  HoldPattern@finiteFourierSinTransform[a_, __] :> a
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

OK, now it's just a simple equation, solve it and transform back:

```
ttsol = u[x, y] /. First@Solve[tteq, u[x, y]]

sol = inverseFiniteFourierSinTransform[
  inverseFiniteFourierSinTransform[ttsol, m, {y, 0, 2}], n, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Finally, an illustration for the solution:

```
Plot3D[Block[{C = 7, HoldForm = Identity}, sol] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]